# bootstrap datetimepicker and fixed table header conflict

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angularjs, bootstrap datetimepicker as input in a form that shows a list on table with a fixed header. Because of this my datetimepicker is scrambled like shown below.

EDIT: Link to [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vqzg6qrCkyNIE9bxliTM?p=preview)

[image]

In css if i remove `float: left;` from below code,then my datepicker is alright. But table is not aligned. Please help me solve this.

```
.table-fixed tbody td, thead th {
            width: 14.2%;
            float: left;
        }
```

Full CSS

```
.table-fixed {
            width: 100%;
        }
.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tr:after {
            content: ' ';
            display: block;
            visibility: hidden;
            clear: both;
        }
.table-fixed thead th {
            height: 60px;
        }        

 .table-fixed thead {
 }
.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
 }

.table-fixed tbody td, thead th {
            width: 14.2%;
            float: left;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, Could you share the link of the site which has an issue or else please share the code via fiddle.

Comment: I tried fiddle, but could not finish it. I am new to fiddle and its tough for me to this post.

Comment: try with plunker then use this link https://plnkr.co/  More information needed to solve your problem so please update your post and put a reply to this comment

Comment: Okay  I will create now for sure and get back to you soon.

Comment: Please see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vqzg6qrCkyNIE9bxliTM?p=preview) Is this enough?

Comment: @Aravind need more code? what part needed? i will update.

Comment: I dont knw exactly where is the problem. so I cant say which one I need. The plunker which u added does not work !

Comment: It does not work means ? i am able to see scrambled datepicker as shown in image. Is there a way to replace float: left; i tried inline, position etc. nothing worked